# Focaltech ft5206 firmware

Tags: bootloader, firmware

I brought a strip of FT5206 chips from Aliexpress, but I have not been able to communicate with the ones I've tried so far. I receive no Ack or response from the I2C bus and nothing from the SPI either, whereas the other pins (RESET, WAKE, INTERRUPT) appear to work OK. I suspect this may be due to lack of firmware installed, so my questions are:

Should the I2C/SPI work with no firmware (i.e are they implemented in hardware)?

If not is there an alternative method to flashing firmware (normal method is over I2C)? - the datasheet I have mentions a bootloader, but gives no details...

If so (to q1) should I just assume I have a bad batch?

Also could anyone suggest a better documented alternative capacitive touch controller - the panels I'm using have 15x10 lines ?